# how to load and extract fonts using webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm Learning webpack and finding some troubles to know

which webpack loader convenient for loading fonts to host them locally, the **"url loader"** is working good for me

but it produce the font as **base64** which I'm not intended to be like that I'd like to extract my fonts.

I tried **"file loader**" but it looks I can't get the correct config or it dosen't work with **webpack 4** I don't know ?

this this my config setup it working good using **url loader**:

```js
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports={
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/.js$/,
                use:['babel-loader'],
                exclude:/node_modules/,

            },
            {
                test:/\.(pug)$/,
                loader:'pug-loader',
                query:{
                    pretty:false
                },
                exclude:/node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    } 
            ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:'file-loader',
                        options:{
                            name:'[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath:'imgs'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.(woff)$/i,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:'url-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

    plugins:[
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/pug/home.pug',
            filename: "index.html",
        }),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/pug/about.pug',
            filename: "about.html",
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({ 
            cssProcessorOptions: { 
                map: { 
                    inline: false, 
                    annotation: true, 
                } 
            } 
            })

    ],

}
```

and this is my tree structure :

```js
C:\~\src
├── assets
|  ├── fonts
|  |  ├── dorid-bold.woff
|  |  └── dorid-Medium.woff
|  └── images
├── index.js
├── pug
|  ├── about.pug
|  ├── abstracts
|  |  ├── base.pug
|  |  └── mixins.pug
|  ├── components
|  |  └── _social-comp.pug
|  ├── home.pug
|  └── layout
|     ├── _footer.pug
|     └── _header.pug
└── sass
   ├── abstracts
   |  ├── _func.scss
   |  ├── _mixin.scss
   |  └── _vars.scss
   ├── base
   |  ├── _base.scss
   |  └── _fonts.scss
   ├── components
   ├── layout
   |  ├── _footer.scss
   |  ├── _header.scss
   |  └── _nav.scss
   ├── main.scss
   ├── pages
   └── vendors
```

Comment: Don't "pack" fonts. Just write normal CSS `@font-face` code, and load that into your site CSS (either bundled or not. There isn't really any reason to bundle those in the slightest) and put your font files in a normal static asset location. Webpack shouldn't be trying to touch those files, or copy those files, or rewrite those files, or do _anything_ to those files. They're _just_ static assets. Serve them like any other normal traditional content.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but webpack check the **url** `src: url('font.woff')` **@font-face**  while bundling scss and getting parse error, How to avoid that ?

Comment: But webpack _shouldn't_. Don't add your `@font-face` rules to your bundle: make it a normal stand-along .css file and load that the normal way with a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="the/location/of/your/font-face.css">` in your page HTML. There is literally no reason to make Webpack or SASS do anything here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm grateful for your help, It wasn't logical for me to bundle the fonts, I got confused a little cause I saw some people bundle it. 
Thanks 